# CSRF token set to null after a put

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring security 6.2.2 and I set my filter chain as suggested here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-integration-javascript-spa

here the snippet:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(createCsrfRepository()).csrfTokenRequestHandler(new SpaCsrfTokenRequestHandler())).cors(withDefaults()).authorizeRequests()
    .....
   }

final class SpaCsrfTokenRequestHandler extends CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler {
        private final CsrfTokenRequestHandler delegate = new XorCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Supplier<CsrfToken> csrfToken) {
            this.delegate.handle(request, response, csrfToken);
        }

        @Override
        public String resolveCsrfTokenValue(HttpServletRequest request, CsrfToken csrfToken) {
            if (StringUtils.hasText(request.getHeader(csrfToken.getHeaderName()))) {
                return super.resolveCsrfTokenValue(request, csrfToken);
            }
            return this.delegate.resolveCsrfTokenValue(request, csrfToken);
        }
    }

    final class CsrfCookieFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
            CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf");
            csrfToken.getToken();
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

What happen is that when I run a PUT operation passing the right X-CSRF-TOKEN in the header, the call works fine but in the response I got:

> Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=; Max-Age=60; Expires=Tue, 12 Mar 2024 16:47:05
> GMT; Domain=local.net; Path=/; Secure;

A part the cookies settings that are ok, you can see I got back a XSRF-TOKEN null.